# Get correct types for @types/node

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have typescript project with node v10.15.3.

I'm trying to use [fs.readdirSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdirsync_path_options) with `{ withFileTypes: true }` option which is supported since v10.10.0

The problem is `/node_modules/@types/node` has old types definitions and if I add them manually all works fine: 
[image]

Otherwise I'm getting obvious error `Argument of type '{ withFileTypes: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | { encoding?: string; }'.`

How do I get correct types for this? `npm update @types/node` didnt help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `npm i @types/node` helped - thought `/node_modules/@types/node` had typing my `package.json` didn't have `@types/node` so update didn't work and old typing were used